# How to remove custom margins / padding and set it back to reading what was defined in the XML Layout

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, layout, margin

In my XML layout I define margins / padding as normal:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
```

I then click a button, and I programatically override this by doing this:

```
param.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
textInputLayout.layoutParams = param
```

Now, I need to click a button again, and it should go back to just reading the margin value that I defined in the XML layout. How can I clear / remove the custom margin?

I would expect there to be something like

```
param.clear()
```

Is there something like this? Or do I from this point forwards always need to override it programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set margins again after second time button click. Below code might help you.

```
// Instance variable
private var isSecondTime = false

// I have used FrameLayout as my parent, Replace with your parent layout. E.g LinearLayout 

    val params = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )
```

And handle button click as per your requirement. Like:

```
        button.setOnClickListener {
        if (!isSecondTime) {
            isSecondTime = true
            params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        } else {
          // setting margin again to 54 dp
            //setMargins(left, top, right, bottom)
            params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, convertDPToPx(54))
        }
        textView.layoutParams = params
    }
```

Converting `DP` to `Pixel`:

```
    private fun convertDPToPx(dip: Int): Int {
    val r: Resources = resources
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            dip.toFloat(),
            r.displayMetrics
    ).toInt()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I feel like it's a bit silly that you can't just clear your custom margins. But for now I guess we're stuck with this type of solution. It works by the way. Thanks!